# How to open a pcap file using SharpPcap

Tags: c#, pcap, packets

im making a c# packet analyzer that would open a pcap file which was created by wireshark...and load the packets into the graphical list.soo,how can i make sharppcap parse the file and show the packets(even in a console window) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that shows how to go about doing what you are asking for.

[ReadFromFile](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET#readFromFile)

I used this about a year ago for a project I was working on.  In the end, there was a issued with that library ( sorry, I cannot remember the exact details ).  So in the end, I had to use WinPCap and pInvoke a native C++ library.  But the open and display of the pcap file worked fine with SharpPcap